# Notification on first login to GCP bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to explore if there is a way to trigger a user alert/popup or a notification to a user on the very first login into Bigquery, the objective is to show a popup/redirect to a page which has the standards/tutorials/best practices of how to use bigquery in the organization

Comment: Also, another thing you can do is just pass to your users a different link with the standards and after a few checks redirect them to BQ console.

Answer (score 1):

Users do not login to BigQuery. Review how Google OAuth 2.0 works in Google Services and Google Cloud. If you want to display a popup, etc. then you will need to implement Google OAuth. You can display anything you want on your login page.

You will not be able to intercept the authorization process at BigQuery.

Comment: Meant the first time they bring up bigquery post login….I was exploring if its possible to either show an alert with some details within the platform or if its possible to automatically fire a query on a table which has the details on the first instance they launch gbq

Comment: @GCPnewbie - What do you mean by **bigquery post login**?